# How to securely login a user from native app (best practices)?

Tags: api, oauth

I am wondering what's a good way to log in users from a native app to my web service.

I have seen implementations that do a soap request then it generates a token pair that expires after 30~ days and it uses that token to make api calls on behalf of that user.  What's the best practice for logging in users and interacting with the api?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no universal answer that works best for every application in the world, on every platform and operating system. The correct answer depends on the application, how it works, and its requirements.

There are many common themes in this area; you mentioned one, such as a time-limited authentication. For some applications, 30 days would be a reasonable time before an authentication token expires; for others applications, a more proper time limit would be in hours, rather than days.

Also a frequent implementation would be an authentication token tied to the client's IP address, or the browser's user agent.  Whether this is a good idea for your application is something that, again, only you know the answer to.

Then, you also have implementation that use signed certificates, instead of authentication tokens, or challenge/response authentication.